# Laravel Multiple Group Chat room using pusher

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5, pusher

I want to create a multiple chat rooms using laravel and pusher. I have created the chatroom where the user logged in can have a group chat with others who are online. But I want to create where something where a users creates a group and the only those users can chat and multiple users can create multiple groups and chat.

I have made the single chatroom from following the youtube videos from the following link:

[Chat Room using Laravel & vue.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rL-dJcxC8X8&t=32s)

I need some help in building as described above.

Comment: With pusher, you would have to track which users are in which chatrooms on your server, and then implement the chatrooms with [private channels](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_private_channels) so that you can restrict access only to the users who are in them.

Comment: You may also want to consider using [ChatKit](https://pusher.com/chatkit) instead. ChatKit also manages rooms and permissions so you don't need to implement this on your server.

Comment: Can you show me some example on how to manage the chat rooms in the pusher. I am very new to this area.

Comment: I will also try to look into the chat-kit too.

Comment: You might find [this](https://pusher.com/tutorials/group-chat-laravel) a useful guide.

Comment: I have already seen that tutorial, but the problem is the tutorial is outdated, it is not working for the latest pusher version.That is the main reason behind asking here

Comment: If you show me which part is out of date, I might be able to help you update it.

Comment: I clone the repository and tried to run the project. It is updating the db but not going in real-time. It shows this following error.
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://ws-your-pusher-app-cluster.pusher.com/app/your-pusher-key?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.1.0&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: I have checked online, they say it would be due to incorrect cluster name but I have named everything correct.

Comment: I have just seen chatkit, i am facing a small issue using it. For creating a room the following is the code given in the documentation: `$chatkit->createRoom([
  'creator_id' => 'sarah',
  'name' => 'my room',
  'private' => false,
  'user_ids' => ['tom', 'will', 'kate']
]);`

Comment: instead of showing assigning the users_ids explicitly, I want to do something where a group is created, the array containing user_ids needs to be assigned to that `user_ids` attribute. but I was getting the following error: `You must provide the ID of the user that you wish to create the room`.Please help me

Comment: The problem is because you are meant to replace `your-pusher-app-cluster` when you initialize the Pusher object with whatever Pusher cluster your app is located in, e.g. `mt1` or `eu`. You cam find the cluster in the dashboard.

Comment: As for that Chatkit issue, I think you are better off asking in the [Pusher slack](https://dash.pusher.com/support).